# After asset precompiling webpage lost all design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recently I changed my apps environment to Production. After that I had error message in log files.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (jquery.fancybox.pack.js isn't precompiled):
```

So I tried execute `rake assets:precompile`, but nothing happened. Error stayed the same.
In Stack Overflow I found sugestion to add this code to **production.rb**

```
  config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
}
```

Then I rake assets:precompile again. Now I got some action like:

```
including asset: /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
including asset: /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/app/assets/javascripts/ga.js
including asset: /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/app/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

....

```
excluding asset: /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.9/vendor/assets/javascripts/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/highcontrast/ui.css
excluding asset: /home3/ecotec11/rails_apps/technorent/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.3/gems/tinymce-rails-3.5.9/vendor/assets/javascripts/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/o2k7/content.css
```

Now I am browsing my web app, but all style and design is gone..

What could cause this problem ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. I did bad research in google.
Found that my log files displayed routing error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/4_600_350-764568941999af034523c215c97b086f.jpg"):
```

Found that I need set in production.rb file

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap, try to clean temp by rake tmp:clear. Needs more information about your gems, and log.